# Get list (key-value dictionary) of static variables, while respecting inheritance

Tags: python

I was wondering whether it is possible to get a list of static variables in a class, while respecting inheritance.

I have a code snippet that returns a key-value dictionary of all static variables within a class:

`dict = {attr: Class.__dict__[attr] for attr in Class.__dict__ if not callable(getattr(Class, attr)) and not attr.startswith('__')}`

The issue is that it only returns the static variables declared within that specific class, but not the ones inherited from its parent class. For example:

```
class Class():
  var1 = 1

  def __init__(self):
    pass

class SubClass(Class):
  var2 = 2

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  dict1 = {attr: Class.__dict__[attr] for attr in Class.__dict__ if not callable(getattr(Class, attr)) and not attr.startswith('__')}
  dict2 = {attr: SubClass.__dict__[attr] for attr in SubClass.__dict__ if not callable(getattr(SubClass, attr)) and not attr.startswith('__')}

  print(dict1)
  print(dict2)

  print('Class: var1 = {}'.format(Class.var1))
  print('SubClass: var1 = {}, var2 = {}'.format(SubClass.var1, SubClass.var2))
```

returns

```
{'var1': 1}
{'var2': 2}
Class: var1 = 1
SubClass: var1 = 1, var2 = 2
```

I was thinking of getting the dictionary for the base class and concatenating it with the dictionary of the subclass, but I am not certain how many levels of inheritance I may need and I'd rather avoid unnecessary headaches.

Is there a way, other than what I suggested above, to get a key-value dictionary of all static variables within a class, including the ones which are inherited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the `dir` built-in function would be appropriate, if you really only care about static variables:

```
# Python 2.7.6
class A(object):
    a_static_var = 'A static var'

class B(A):
    b_static_var = 'B static var'

print dir(B)
```

Prints:

```
['__class__',
 ...<etc>...,
 'a_static_var',
 'b_static_var']
```

To get a dictionary of static variables and their values (someone might be able to recommend a better method for filtering the values, rather than using `startswith('_')`):

```
# build dict of non-callable, non-private static variables and their values
static_var_vals = {}
for attr_name in dir(B):
    if not attr_name.startswith('_'):
        attr = getattr(B, attr_name):

        if not callable(attr):
            static_var_vals[attr_name] = attr
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. `dir()` does return inherited static variables as well, but not their values. I am interested in a solution that returns a key-value dictionary.

Comment: @sudosensei -- see my addition

Comment: Nice one! Works (almost) perfectly. May I suggest you also add `and not callable(getattr(B, attr))` such that functions are ignored, and the answer is complete? Thanks once again. `:-)`

Comment: @sudosensei -- done; expanded to for-loop due to the multiple conditions (a bit easier to read IMO than having both conditions in a dict comprehension)